# 37:30:55 format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column that includes time values. I want to calculate the summation of this column, and am aware that it will exceed the 24-hour time format.

When I tried it I get an error. I want the summation to be similar to an Excel summation i.e., **37:30:55**

Please help:

```
Alter Procedure [dbo].[OverTime]

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT     dbo.TBL_Justification.Justification_Cisco
          ,dbo.TBL_HC.HC_AgentName, dbo.TBL_HC.HC_Q
          ,dbo.TBL_HC.HC_Site
          ,dbo.TBL_HC.HC_SPV
          ,dbo.TBL_HC.HC_TeamLeader
          ,dbo.TBL_WFM.WFM_Resolution
          ,Sum(dbo.TBL_Justification.Justification_Event_Duration)

FROM       dbo.TBL_Justification LEFT OUTER JOIN
                       dbo.TBL_WFM ON dbo.TBL_Justification.Justification_ID = dbo.TBL_WFM.WFM_JustificationID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                       dbo.TBL_HC ON dbo.TBL_Justification.Justification_Cisco = dbo.TBL_HC.HC_Cisco
WHERE                 (dbo.TBL_WFM.WFM_Resolution = 'Closed Successfully') OR
                      (dbo.TBL_WFM.WFM_Resolution = 'Done As Exception') OR
                      (dbo.TBL_WFM.WFM_Resolution = 'Done After Validation')
END
```

Comment: See http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server, but the short answer is to just sum seconds or minutes, and do the formatting client side.

Comment: Or you could create your own CLR timestamp datatype.

Comment: great article thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Seconds int = 
    37 * (60 * 60) -- Hour
    + 30 * 60 -- Minute
    + 55 -- Second

-- This is h:mm:ss format
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), @Seconds / (60 * 60)) + ':' -- Max. 10 precision for hour
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), @Seconds % (60 * 60) / 60), 2) + ':' 
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), @Seconds % 60), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small scalar function that takes a duration in seconds and returns it in the format you've requested:

```
create function fmtSeconds (@s int)
returns varchar(10)
as
begin
    declare @h varchar(5), @m varchar(2);
    set @h = @s/(60*60);
    set @s -= @h * 60*60;

    set @m = @s/60;
    set @s -= @m * 60;

    return @h + ':' + @m + ':' + cast(@s as varchar(2));
end
go
--sample call
declare @seconds int = 55 + 30*60 + 37*60*60;
select dbo.fmtSeconds(@seconds);
go
```

I agree with the sentiment in the comments above about letting this be a client-side concern if that's an option for you.